# Material UI Custom Color Palette Names in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to add a custom color palette to my material ui theme.

I am following the Material UI documentation here [Material UI Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#typescript-2)

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface PaletteColor {
    main: string;
    ten: string;
    twenty: string;
    thirty: string;
    forty: string;
    fifty: string;
    sixty: string;
    seventy: string;
    eight: string;
    ninty: string;
    nintyFive: string;
  }

const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
    primary: {
      ten: customPalette.primary10,
      twenty: customPalette.primary20,
      thirty: customPalette.primary30,
      main: customPalette.primary40,
      fifty: customPalette.primary50,
      sixty: customPalette.primary60,
      seventy: customPalette.primary70,
      eight: customPalette.primary80,
      ninty: customPalette.primary90,
      nintyFive: customPalette.primary95,
    },
}})
```

Now I would expect that `theme.palette.primary.ten` would be equal to the `primary10` color, however it is showing as undefined. As are the rest of my primary colors, except for main.

Answer (score 0):

1. The fields in the documentation are optional, but yours is not.

```js
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface PaletteColor {
    darker?: string;
  }

  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    darker?: string;
  }
}
```

2. Where do you get this object? "customPalette"